# Count number of candles above EMA50

Tags: pine-script

Need some advise with pine script
I want to write a code, counting number of candles above EMA50,
once close dropped below EMA50, this counter reset to zero :

'''

```
MA_long = ema(close,50)
// Counting how many candles are above the MA_long
barsAboveMA = 0
if close > MA_long
    for i = 1 to 9999
        if close[i] < MA_long
            break
        barsAboveMA := barsAboveMA + 1
```

'''

But this code having strange performance, not working correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that you didn't use the history-referencing operator with MA_long in your *for* loop. That means that you compare **past** *close* values with the value of the EMA on the **current** bar (also note that you start comparing from *close[1]* and don't use the *close* value from the current bar).

A better way to implement a counter like that in Pine would be using the *var* keyword. With *var*, the variable will not reset to 0 on every bar. Do this and then you can modify it without for loops:

```
MA_long = ema(close,50)
var barsAboveMA = 0 // when var is used, the value is not reset to 0 at the start of every bar
if close > MA_long
    barsAboveMA := barsAboveMA + 1
else
    barsAboveMA := 0
plot(barsAboveMA)
```